# Excel save in AlaSQL not saving data correctly

Tags: javascript, json, alasql

I have an array of objects and I am using alaSQL to save it as an excel file but I am unable to save it.
[image: Screenshot for of the excel saved.]

```
      vm.excelSave = function(){
         alasql.promise('SELECT * INTO XLSX("Statistics.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [vm.dataPerformance])
            .then(function (res) {
                // console.log(res);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                // console.log(err);
            })
```

Comment: Post the code that tells alaSQL to save in Excel format

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Posted